# Can I use the Playstation Eye webcam's microphone with Raspberry

Tags: webcam, windows-iot

I'm evaluating microphones to use with a Raspberry for a voice controlled project. The preferred operating system would be Window 10 IoT Core.

An inexpensive yet probably pretty good microphone for far field voice recognition would be the Playstation Eye ([http://www.amazon.com/PlayStation-Eye-3/dp/B000VTQ3LU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VTQ3LU)).

Is there any chance of getting this to work with the Raspberry in terms of device compatibility, available drivers etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about purchasing a product.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out!

Worth a try...Good luck

visit **[this](http://sanjosetech.blogspot.se/2013/03/gstreamer-webcam-microphone-test.html)** page.

or [this](http://raspberrypi-hacks.com/11/control-your-raspberry-pi-via-voice-control/) one.

Sorry I couldn't find any examples on Stack overflow, hope it helps